# How do I read a text file in python via PowerShell? Windows 10

Tags: python, powershell

I'm having problems reading text files into my python programs.

```
import sys

words = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

I'm reading the file in through stdin but when I try to execute the program I'm getting this error.

```
PS> python evil_61.py < evilwords.txt

At line:1 char:19
+ python evil_61.py < evilwords.txt
+                   ~

The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

Could someone tell me how to run these kinds of programs as it is essential for my course and I'd rather use Windows than Linux.

Answer (score 8):

Since `<` for input redirection is not supported in PowerShell, use `Get-Content` in a pipeline instead:

```
Get-Content evilwords.txt | python evil_61.py
```

<sup>Note: Adding the `-Raw` switch - which reads a file as a single, multi-line string - would speed things up in principle (at the expense of increased memory consumption), but PowerShell *invariably appends a newline* to data piped to external programs, as of PowerShell 7.2 (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372333/45375)), so *the target program will typically see an extra, empty line at the end*. `Get-Content`'s default behavior of line-by-line streaming avoids that.</sup>

Beware character-encoding issues:

- [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), in the absence of an `-Encoding` argument, assumes the following encoding:

  - *Windows PowerShell*  (the built-into-Windows edition whose latest and final version is 5.1): the active **ANSI** code page, which is implied by the active legacy system locale (language for non-Unicode programs).
  - [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md): (BOM-less) **UTF-8**
- On passing the lines through the pipeline, they are (re-)encoded based on the encoding stored in the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding), which defaults to:

  - *Windows PowerShell*: **ASCII**(!)
  - *PowerShell (Core) 7+*: (BOM-less) **UTF-8**

As you can see, only *PowerShell (Core) 7+* exhibits *consistent* behavior, though, unfortunately, as of PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.9, this doesn't yet extend to capturing output *from* external programs, because the encoding that controls the interpretation of received data, stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding]`, still defaults to the system's active *OEM* code page - see [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233).

Answer (score 0):

Consider passing the text file as an argument at command line for Python script to use. All command line arguments (including file name) come stored in the [sys.argv](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) list:

**Python** Script *(in evil_61.py)*

```
import sys

txtfile = sys.argv[1]
with open(txtfile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

**PowerShell** Command

```
PS> python evil_61.py evilwords.txt
```