# Piping Text To An External Program Appends A Trailing Newline

Tags: linux, powershell, hash, pipe, newline

I have been comparing hash values between multiple systems and was surprised to find that PowerShells hash values are different than that of other terminals.

Linux terminals (CygWin, Bash for Windows, etc.) and Windows Command Prompt are all showing the same hash where as PowerShell is showing a different hash value.

[image: Linux_Vs_PShell_Hash_Compare.png]

This was tested using SHA256 but found the same issue when using other algorithms like md5.

**Encoding Update:**

Tried changing the PShell encoding but it did not have any effect on the returned hash values.

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding.BodyName 
iso-8859-1
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
utf-8
```

**GitHub PowerShell Issue**

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5974

Comment: You know that in PowerShell, `echo -n` is actually `Write-Output -NoEnumerate` due to aliases, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing PowerShell's default output encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8), [UTF-8 output from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22349139/608639), [Set the encoding to ANSI in PowerShell 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37700256/608639), etc.

Comment: Tried changing the encoding to UTF-8 but it doesn't change the hash results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**:

**[*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) v7.4+** now **supports raw byte handling with external programs** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375)), which enables the following, simpler solutions:

- On *Unix*-like platforms:

```bash
# PS v7.4+ only, on Unix-like platforms
# No newline will be appended; the raw byte output from external program printf
# is passed through.
printf %s 'string' | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac authcode
```

- On *Windows* (works on Unix too):

```bash
# PS v7.4+ only, on any supported platform.
# Send the *byte* representation of the string to external program openssl.
# If you were to send the string directly, PowerShell would append a newline.
, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('string') | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac authcode
```

The **following therefore applies only to *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell (Core) v7.3-***.

---

**tl;dr:**

**When PowerShell pipes a string to an *external program***:

- It *encodes* it using the character encoding stored in the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding)
- It *invariably appends a trailing (platform-appropriate) newline*.

Therefore, the **key is to avoid *PowerShell's* pipeline** in favor of the native shell's, so as to **prevent implicit addition of a trailing newline**:

- If you're running your command on a ***Unix***-like platform (using PowerShell *Core*):

```bash
sh -c "printf %s 'string' | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac authcode"
```

<sup>`printf %s` is the *portable* alternative to `echo -n`. If the string contains `'` chars., *double* them or use `` `"...`" `` quoting instead.</sup>

- In case you need to do this on ***Windows* via `cmd.exe`**, things get even trickier, because `cmd.exe` doesn't directly support echoing without a trailing newline:

```bash
cmd /c "<NUL set /p =`"string`"| openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac authcode"
```

<sup>Note that there must be *no space before* `|` for this to work. For an explanation and the limitations of this solution, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33322238/45375).</sup>

Encoding issues would only arise if the string contained non-ASCII characters *and* you're running in *Windows* PowerShell; in that event, first set `$OutputEncoding` to the encoding that the target utility expects, typically UTF-8: `$OutputEncoding = [Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()`

---

- **PowerShell *invariably* appends a *trailing newline* when you send a string without one via the pipeline to an *external* utility**, which is the reason for the difference you're observing (that trailing newline will be a LF only on Unix platforms, and a CRLF sequence on Windows).

  - You can keep track of efforts to address this problem in [GitHub issue #5974](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5974), opened by the OP.
- Additionally, **in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell (Core) up to v7.3.x, PowerShell's pipeline is invariably *text*-based when it comes to piping data to *external* programs**; the internally UTF-16LE-based PowerShell (.NET) strings are transcoded based on the encoding stored in the automatic `$OutputEncoding` variable, which defaults to ASCII-only encoding in *Windows* PowerShell, and to UTF-8 encoding in PowerShell *Core* (both on Windows and on Unix-like platforms).

  - ***PowerShell (Core) v7.4+* now *does* support raw byte processing with external programs** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375).
- The fact that `echo -n` in PowerShell does *not* produce a string without a trailing newline is therefore *incidental* to your problem; for the sake of completeness, here's an explanation:

  - `echo` is an alias for PowerShell's [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet, which - in the context of piping to *external* programs - writes *text* to the standard input of the program in the *next* pipeline segment (similar to Bash / cmd.exe's `echo`).
  - `-n` is interpreted as an (unambiguous) abbreviation for `Write-Output`'s `-NoEnumerate` switch.
  - `-NoEnumerate` only applies when writing *multiple* objects, so it has no effect here.
  - Therefore, in short: in PowerShell, `echo -n "string"` is the same as `Write-Output -NoEnumerate "string"`, which - because only a single string is output - is the same as `Write-Output "string"`, which, in turn, is the same as just using `"string"`, relying on PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior.
  - `Write-Output` has no option to suppress a trailing newline, and even if it did, using a pipeline to pipe to an *external* program would add it back in.

Answer (score 1):

Linux terminals and PowerShell use different encodings. So real bytes produced by `echo -n "string"` are different. I tried it on my Linux Mint terminal and Windows 10 PowerShell. Here what I got:

Linux Mint:

```
73 74 72 69 6E 67
```

Windows 10:

```
FF FE 73 00 74 00 72 00 69 00 6E 00 67 00 0D 00 0A 00
```

It seems that Linux terminals use UTF-8 and Windows PowerShell uses UTF-16 with a BOM. Also in PowerShell you cannot use '-n' parameter for echo. So echo places newline characters `\r\n` (`0D 00 0A 00`) at the end of the "string".

**Edit:** As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) said below, Windows PowerShell uses ASCII by default when piping.

Comment: I'm not a PowerShell person, but everything I have seen about it is awful for a person from a Unix/Linux background who expects it to act like shell scripting. I gave up on PowerShell once I saw what I had to do for a simple `grep` and `sed`.

Comment: PowerShell does _not_ use UTF-16LE when _piping_ to external programs, at least by default.  The automatic `$OutputEncoding` variable determines the encoding that is used when piping to external programs such as `openssl`, which defaults to ASCII in _Windows_ PowerShell, and UTF-8 in PowerShell _Core_. It is indeed the trailing newline that is invariably added that causes the problem here; you _can_ use `-n` with `echo` in PowerShell, but its semantics are different (`echo -n` is the equivalent of `Write-Output -NoEnumerate`).

Comment: @jwww: PowerShell is used to being its own world, historically speaking; with its transition to being cross-platform, it still has a few things to learn when it comes to interacting with external utilities, which are much more important in the Unix world than they are in the Windows world. I encourage you to help that process along at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

Comment: @Pie: Thanks; to recap: the real issue is that the _PowerShell pipeline_ itself _when piping to external programs_ appends a trailing newline; it is not an _encoding_ problem (except possibly in _Windows PowerShell_ with a string that contains _non-ASCII_ characters). Because this answer focuses on encoding (and misrepresents how transcoding works with _external_ programs), it's a -1 from me.