# How to ensure Python prints UTF-8 (and not UTF-16-LE) when piped in PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to print text as UTF-8 when piped (to, for example, a file), so on Python 3.7.3 on Windows 10 via PowerShell, I'm doing this:

```py
import sys

if not sys.stdout.isatty():
    sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

print("Mamma mia.")
```

When run as `encodingtest.py > test.txt`, `test.txt` then turns out to be this:

```
00000000  FF FE 4D 00 61 00 6D 00 6D 00 61 00 20 00 6D 00  ÿþM.a.m.m.a. .m.
00000010  69 00 61 00 2E 00 0D 00 0A 00                    i.a.......
```

Mysteriously enough, it starts with `FF FE`, which is the byte-order marker for UTF-16-LE – and null bytes are printed between the characters (as UTF-16 would have it)! However, when I run it via CMD rather than PowerShell, it prints UTF-8 just fine. **How do I get Python to print UTF-8 even when piped via PowerShell?**

I could run `encodingtest.py | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 test.txt` instead, but **is there a way to ensure the output encoding program-side?**

Comment: Windows is endlessly special.

Comment: Have you verified that `isatty()` is returning the correct value?

Comment: Don't use `>`, it defaults to UTF16LE in PowerShell. Pipe to `Set-Content` and `Out-File` instead

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen does that mean Powershell itself is reinterpreting the byte stream?

Comment: For the second question, check on bottom of https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin on how to force to write binary data (so you need probably a wrapper, and to encode data explicitly)

Comment: @MarkRansom, yes, invariably: PowerShell always decodes as text first, then re-encodes on output to a file.

Comment: @mklement0 how is it possible that cmd.exe handles this so much more sensibly?  The stream of bytes concept has been around at least 40 years now, what was Microsoft thinking when they broke it?

Comment: @MarkRansom, please see the bottom section I've just added to my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**:

- **[*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) v7.4+** now ***does* support raw byte handling with external programs** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375).
- The **following therefore applies only to *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell (Core) 7.3-***

---

**PowerShell fundamentally doesn't support processing *raw* output (a stream of *bytes*) from external programs**:

- It invariably *decodes* such output as *text*, using the character encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for more information.
- Once decoded, it uses *its* default character encoding for file-output operations such as `>` (effectively an alias for the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet), which for `>` are:

  - *Windows PowerShell (up to v5.1)*: "Unicode", i.e. UTF-16LE (which is what you're seeing)
  - *PowerShell (Core, v6+)*: BOM-less UTF-8 (now applied *consistently* across all cmdlets, unlike in Windows PowerShell).

In other words: **Even use of just `>` involves a character decoding and re-encoding cycle, with no relationship between the original and the resulting encoding.**

---

Therefore:

- (Temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()`
- Pipe the output from your Python script call to `Out-File` - or, preferably, if the input is known to be *strings* already (always true for external-program calls) - [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) with `Encoding utf8`.

  - Caveat: In *Windows PowerShell*, you'll *invariably* get a UTF-8 file *with a BOM* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375) for a workaround). In *PowerShell (Core)*, you'll get one *without* a BOM (as you would by default), but can opt to create one with `-Encoding utf8BOM`.

To put it all together (saving and restoring the original `[Console]::OutputEncoding` not shown):

```bash
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
encodingtest.py | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 test.txt
```

Modifying `[Console]::OutputEncoding` isn't necessary if you've switched to UTF-8 *system-wide*, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375), but note that this Windows 10 feature is still in beta as of this writing and has far-reaching consequences.

---

**Alternatively, call via `cmd.exe`**, which *does* pass the raw bytes through to a file with `>`:

```bash
cmd /c 'encodingtest.py > test.txt'
```

This technique (which analogously applies to Unix-like platforms via `/bin/sh -c`) is the general workaround for the lack of raw byte processing (see below).

---

**Background information: Lack of support for raw byte streams in PowerShell's pipeline:**

PowerShell's pipeline is *object*-based, which means that it is instances of *.NET types* that flow through it. This evolution of the traditional, binary-only pipeline is the key to PowerShell's power and versatility.

*Everything* in PowerShell is mediated via pipelines, including use of the redirection operator `>`, with `... > foo.txt` in effect being syntactic sugar for `... | Out-File foo.txt`

- For *PowerShell-native commands*, which invariably output .NET objects, *some* form of encoding is necessary in order to write these objects to a file in a meaningful way (unless the objects are strings already, raw byte representations wouldn't make any sense), so *text* representations based on PowerShell's for-display output formatting systems are used (which, incidentally, is the reason why `>` with non-string input is generally unsuited to producing files for later *programmatic* processing).
- For *external programs*, PowerShell has chosen to only ever communicate with them via *text* (strings), which on receiving output involves the inevitable decoding of the raw bytes received into .NET strings, as described above.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for more information.

**This lack of support for raw byte streams is *problematic***:
Unless you call the underlying .NET APIs directly to explicitly handle byte streams (which would be quite cumbersome), the cycle of decoding and re-encoding as text:

- can *alter the data*, interfering not only with sending byte stream to *files*, but also with piping data *between/to* external programs; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372333/45375) for an example.
- can significantly *degrade performance*.

Historically, when PowerShell was a Windows-only shell, this wasn't much of a problem, because the Windows world didn't have many capable CLIs (command-line interfaces (utilities)) worth calling, so staying within the realm of PowerShell was usually sufficient (performance problems notwithstanding).

In an increasingly cross-platform world, however, and especially on Unix-like platforms, capable CLIs abound and are sometimes indispensable for *high-performance* operations.

Therefore, **PowerShell should support raw byte streams at least *on demand*, and *situationally* even *automatically*** when detecting that data is being piped *between two external programs*. See [GitHub issue #1908](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1908) and [GitHub issue #5974](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5974).

Comment: Mamma mia. I see! Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Here's hoping this feature comes to PowerShell, for those not-all-that-rare times you want programs to have a well-defined encoding for piped data!