# Curl Powershell windows 10 slower than command prompt why?

Tags: windows, powershell, curl, download

Just a pretty stand curl command call an S3 end point for download using all default values.  On a mac, or on a PC using command line I get 103MBsec if cached on cdn and 80mbsec otherwise.  Same command, same bucket, same object,  using "curl.exe" and I get 1MBSec when call through powershell.  I guess powershell does something different that make it's totally slow?   I tried using newest curl binary but still the same.
I guess I am misunderstanding what powershell is doing when I use a curl command

```
curl.exe yourfileonS3 >> output.bin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**:

- **[*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) v7.4+** now ***does* support raw byte handling with external programs** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375).
- The **following therefore applies only to *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell (Core) v7.3-***

---

To complement [briantist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68795262/45375):

- In PowerShell, the [redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `>` and `>>` are in effect aliases of [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and `Out-File -Append`.
- `>` and `>>` are therefore *not* mere byte-stream conduits, and, in fact, ***Windows PowerShell* and PowerShell (Core) *up to v7.3* do *not* support sending *raw byte output* to a file.**

  - Instead, **PowerShell *invariably* decodes output from any external program as *text*** (`[string]` instances), based on the character encoding reported by `[Console]::OutputEncoding]` and then, on saving to the target file with `Out-File` (possibly via `>` / `>>`), *re-encodes* these strings, using that cmdlet's default character encoding (unless overridden with `-Encoding` in an explicit `Out-File` call).
  - **Not only does this not preserve the external program's raw byte
    output, it adds significant overhead.**

**To get raw byte processing, call `cmd.exe`<sup>[1]</sup> and use *its* redirection operators**:

```
cmd /c 'curl.exe yourfileonS3 >> output.bin'
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68488098/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] On Unix-like platforms, use `sh -c 'curl yourfileonS3 >> output.bin'`</sup>

Comment: Awesome! This was the missing piece I didn't have time to complete. And I suspect that not being able to handle raw bytes is a big deal when trying to download binary data into a file. Excellent answer as usual.

Answer (score 3):

See [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68795616/3905079) for full context on this (I recommend accepting that one!), and the important point that handling of byte streams in redirection is **problematic and error prone** in PowerShell and should be avoided.

---

So I looked into this and I believe the reason is that `>>` (file redirection) is the slow part.

I originally suspected you might be calling `curl` (which is aliased to `Invoke-WebRequest` in Windows PowerShell), but I was able to reproduce the speed difference between `curl.exe` directly in PowerShell vs `cmd.exe`, and measure it, this way:

```
# call curl.exe and do redirection in PowerShell
Measure-Command -Expression { curl.exe https://uploader.codecov.io/v0.1.0_6943/linux/codecov >> delme.bin }

del delme.bin

# call cmd.exe and do redirection there
Measure-Command -Expression { & cmd.exe /c 'curl.exe https://uploader.codecov.io/v0.1.0_6943/linux/codecov >> delme.bin' }

del delme.bin
```

This was enough to show a stark difference.

I also confirmed that this problem is a little bit worse in Windows PowerShell as opposed to later cross-platform versions (`pwsh.exe`). In Windows, with version 7.1.0, the same commands above still show a large difference.

Comment: Yes for sure I noticed that curl just calls invoke-webrequest too.  I'll try and do without the >>