# Difference in running C++ program in command prompt and PowerShell

Tags: c++, c, powershell, command-prompt

In C and C++ command-line programs, is there any differences between running your programs within command prompt or within PowerShell? (e.g.: exception handling, I/O speed, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**:

- **[*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) v7.4+** now ***does* support raw byte handling with external programs** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375).
- The **following therefore applies only to *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell (Core) 7.3-***

---

The main difference:

- **`cmd.exe` provides true *binary* (byte-stream) conduits**, so that `>`, the redirection operator, can capture an external program's raw byte output.
- ***Windows PowerShell*** and **PowerShell (Core) *up to v7.3*** only ever **use *text* (strings) to communicate with external programs**, both on in- and output, which means that **external-program output is *invariably decoded to .NET strings***, which has the following implications:

  - Even when only using PowerShell's `>` operator to send an external program's output to a file, each line output by an external program is first *decoded* into a .NET string and then, on saving to the target file, *encoded again*, in this case using the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet's default encoding, which the `>` operator is an effective alias of.

    - In *Windows PowerShell*, that (cmdlet-specific) encoding is UTF-16LE ("Unicode"), whereas in *PowerShell (Core) 6+*, it is BOM-less UTF-8, the encoding used *consistently* in that PowerShell edition.
  - **This decoding-reencoding cycle not only *slows things down***, but also means:

    - For *text* output, the input character encoding (as decoded from the external program) may be different from the output-by-PowerShell character encoding.
    - ***Binary* in- and output is *fundamentally unsupported***.

      - The simplest **workaround** is to delegate to `cmd.exe` with `cmd /c ...` (on Windows) and to `/bin/sh` with `sh -c ...` (on Unix-like platforms.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68488098/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The program itself is just a process, it doesn't really matter how you launch it.

The notable difference is that, while both consoles connect themselves to the standard input and output streams of the process, everyone has its own performance while renderizing it, so the IO calls may be more or less impacted by this.

Technically, a console is just a program that invokes your program and graphically shows your output (and other things).