# Start program with PowerShell without waiting for input

Tags: powershell, stdin, exit

I was wondering if this Bash command could be converted to PowerShell:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host:port </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

The current script (not working):

```
.\openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host:port 2>$null | .\openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

The missing `</dev/null` makes it wait infinitely for input. Is there a PowerShell alternative for that syntax?

`<$null` doesn't work since `<` is reserved for future use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have experience with powershell, but the "normal" command shell uses `NUL` for the bitbucket. Did you try `<NUL` with the Powershell?

Comment: Pipe an empty string to `openssl s_client`: `'' |.\openssl s_client ...`. Or a NUL byte: `[char]0 |.\openssl s_client ...`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, only `@() | ...` truly provides _no_ input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The equivalent of `</dev/null` is `@() | ...`**, as the following simplified example shows:

```
# Equivalent of `cat -n </dev/null` in Bash, for instance.
@() | cat -n
```

- PowerShell doesn't support the `<` operator at all, as of PowerShell 7.2;<sup>[1]</sup> **to send data that an external program sees via its stdin stream, it must be *piped*** (`|`) to it, as shown above.
- **Piping an *empty array* (`@()`) effectively provides *no* stdin input**,<sup>[2]</sup> as `</dev/null` does in POSIX-compatible shells.

Note that piping `''` or `` "`0" `` / `[char] 0` does *not* work, because PowerShell invariably *appends a newline* to the data, which it invariably sends as *text*.

However, there may be an **additional problem**:

**Your specific command joins two *external programs* with a *PowerShell* pipeline**, which **runs the risk of inadvertent modification of the data being streamed**, because this invariably involves *decoding as text* of the first process' output and *re-encoding as text* before sending it to the second process - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68488098/45375) for more information.

The **workaround** is to **call the *platform-native shell*'s CLI**, whose `|` operator streams data unmodified; the platform-native shell also allow use of `<`:

On *Windows*, use `cmd /c` and `NUL` in lieu of `/dev/null`:

```
cmd /c 'openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host:port <NUL 2>NUL | openssl x509 -noout -dates'
```

On *Unix*-like platforms, use `sh -c` (`/dev/null` can be used as-is):

```
sh -c 'openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host:port </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates'
```

---

<sup>[1] The error message when trying to use `<` mentions "reserved for future use", but there is no telling if this operator will ever be implemented, and given that the pipeline covers its functionality I'd say that chances are slim.</sup>

<sup>[2] The reason is that PowerShell *enumerates* collections (such as arrays) in the pipeline, i.e. it sends the elements *one by one*. An empty collection by definition has no elements, so there is nothing to send.</sup>