# Bash base64 has an additional character instead of an equals versus powershell

Tags: linux, powershell, encoding, base64

If I do the following in powershell:

`$b = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("helloworld")`

`[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($b)`

The output is:

`aGVsbG93b3JsZA==`

If I go into bash and do the same thing:

`echo "helloworld" | base64` then the result is:

`aGVsbG93b3JsZAo=`

So in bash, instead of the first `=` its an `o`. Why is that?

Comment: As an aside: _PowerShell's_ pipeline (`|`)  _invariably appends a newline_ when piping to external programs such as `bash64`, so if you run stackprotector's solution _from PowerShell_, you'll again get the newline. That is, _from PowerShell_ `/bin/echo -n "helloworld" | base64` (or `printf "helloworld" | base64` or just `"helloworld" | base64`) yields the same as `/bin/echo "helloworld" | base64`, namely `aGVsbG93b3JsZAo=` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372333/45375).

Answer (score 2):

In bash,

```
echo "helloworld" | base64
```

will add a newline character (`\n` or `0A` in hex) to `helloworld`. Use

```
echo -n "helloworld" | base64
```

instead.

Comment: True. Calling GetBytes("helloworld`n") will give the same Base64 encoding in Powershell. Note the backtick escape, which is used in Powershell instead of the more common backslash.