# Import RSA Public key for string encryption in Powershell 5

Tags: powershell, encryption, rsa

I am working on a non-Powershell tool (NodeJS) that will use Powershell for displaying a password prompt. For the purposes of this question, that means the following:

- I invoke the Powershell script with a public key.
- The public key will be used to encrypt the password given by the user.
- The Powershell script outputs the encrypted password.
- I can't use a version of Powershell that does not ship with Windows, so I'm stuck at Powershell 5.

For the life of me, I can't figure out a way to get the public key into a class that does encryption.

Some of the things I tried:

```
$rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$rsa.ImportFromPem($publicKeyPem)
# Method invocation failed because [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng] does not contain a method named 'ImportFromPem'.

$rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$rsa.Import()
# Method invocation failed because [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider] does not contain a method named 'Import'.

$rsa = [System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm]::Create()
$rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey()
# Method invocation failed because [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider] does not contain a method named 'ImportRSAPublicKey'.
```

I definitely tried more options, all running into the same issue where the function does not exist. Because of this, I can't get it to import the key. When generating a new key pair in Powershell, I can successfully encrypt and decrypt. But that does not help me here.

This question is similar to [Encrypting and Encoding a password string with a public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76146132/encrypting-and-encoding-a-password-string-with-a-public-key). But that solution is no help for me since its solution requires Powershell > 5.

I'm I trying to do something weird here? Surely using an existing public key for encryption shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: Powershell uses c# Net Library.  So you can use c# methods in powershell.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243646/how-to-read-a-pem-rsa-private-key-from-net

Comment: That answer uses the `ImportFromPem` method, which does not exist in PowerShell for some reason. See the first option in the code block

Comment: You write nothing about format and encoding of your public key. Specify this or post a sample key. There are many different key formats, of which Powershell 5 supports only a few. If your key is in an unsupported format, is it possible to convert the key to a supported format with a tool (e.g. an online tool)?

Comment: @Topaco I can adapt the format and encoding of the key. I've tried it in `pem` and `der` formats with various encodings like `pkcs1`, `pkcs8`, `spki`. I was unable to import any of them into Powershell.
The only big one I haven't tried is the `xml` formatted one since I have not found an easy way to generate it on the NodeJS side yet.

Comment: [`ImportFromPem` requires .NET v5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importfrompem?view=net-8.0#applies-to). Check which versions of .NET are installed on your computer [using this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495491/3705191). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Powershell 5 does not support importing RSA public keys in X.509/SPKI or PKCS#1 format (note that PKCS#8 is a private key format), neither PEM nor DER encoded.
XML is supported (via [`FromXmlString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.fromxmlstring?view=netframework-4.8.1)), but not by the *crypto* module of NodeJS.

However, it is possible to export the RSA public key in NodeJS in JWK format ([supported since v15.9.0](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#keyobjectexportoptions)). The JWK can be easily converted to the XML format, especially for public RSA keys, since they contain only two parameters, the modulus (`n`) and the public exponent (`e`).
Once the key is in XML format, it can be imported with `FromXmlString()`.

The following Powershell script imports a public key in JWK format (via conversion to the XML format) and performs an RSA encryption with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding:

```bash
# Function to convert from Base64url to Base64
function ToBase64($b64Url) {
    $b64 = $b64Url.Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');
    switch ( $b64Url.Length % 4 )
    {
        2 { $b64 += "=="; break }
        3 { $b64 += "="; break    }
    }
    return $b64
}

# Input: Public RSA key as JWK
$publicKeyJwk = '{"kty":"RSA","n":"sucdbBGl3zbrWewgHMYqDiToF9EUDFlTUp7zi8F-Gu1cbkZgY_ZzTZsbsQtWu5QlvCIp75U_tDDqogA5RCgGOLrrgL_1sDQqktG6erkjpNmvRqRk2QQc3fVLBPlPXJVmLDV7zwcZTgBwCl-3gO6V-PndTENi17j5aW697RV44ZFIaFBvv74kb7gas-71NE8mKbahlIwAdssk2xHm0E81CvNwBk3ISuNY_vBrDHLXpjlJqUUe2AHMMO_zO4rWEs-fQ5lSlAEa7Un3wRodR-ETJsra-AP81-vwyPPaCA9jkkKsRATDfvunBWyjwFAVSck_TzOaOeKgyGj7MQ4KnuzGRw","e":"AQAB"}';

# Extract modulus (n) and public exponent (e)
$keyParams = $publicKeyJwk | ConvertFrom-Json
$nB64url = $keyParams.n 
$eB64url = $keyParams.e 

# Convert modulus and public exponent from Base64url to Base64
$nB64 = ToBase64($nB64url);
$eB64 = ToBase64($eB64url);

# Create public RSA key in XML format
$publicKeyXml = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>" + $nB64 + "</Modulus><Exponent>" + $eB64 + "</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
Write-Output $publicKeyXml;

# Import key 
$rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$rsa.FromXmlString($publicKeyXml)

# Encrypt with RSA and PKCS#1 v1.5 padding
$plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
[byte[]] $plaintextBytes = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($plaintext) 
$ciphertext = $rsa.Encrypt($plaintextBytes, [System.Security.Cryptography.RSAEncryptionPadding]::Pkcs1)
$ciphertextB64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($ciphertext)

#Output Base64 encoded ciphertext
Write-Output $ciphertextB64
```

---

A test is possible by generating an RSA key pair with the following NodeJS code:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto')

var { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {modulusLength: 2048})
var pubkeyjwk = publicKey.export({format:'jwk'})
console.log(JSON.stringify(pubkeyjwk))

var privatejwk = privateKey.export({type:'pkcs1', format:'pem'})
console.log(privatejwk)
```

The NodeJS code exports the public key as JWK and the private key as PEM encoded PKCS#1 key.

The exported public key can be used in the above Powershell script.
The ciphertext generated by the Powershell script can be decrypted with the private key using a suitable code/tool (e.g. [*CyberChef*](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27,true,false)RSA_Decrypt(%27-----BEGIN%20RSA%20PRIVATE%20KEY-----%5CnMIIEowIBAAKCAQEAsucdbBGl3zbrWewgHMYqDiToF9EUDFlTUp7zi8F%2BGu1cbkZg%5CnY/ZzTZsbsQtWu5QlvCIp75U/tDDqogA5RCgGOLrrgL/1sDQqktG6erkjpNmvRqRk%5Cn2QQc3fVLBPlPXJVmLDV7zwcZTgBwCl%2B3gO6V%2BPndTENi17j5aW697RV44ZFIaFBv%5Cnv74kb7gas%2B71NE8mKbahlIwAdssk2xHm0E81CvNwBk3ISuNY/vBrDHLXpjlJqUUe%5Cn2AHMMO/zO4rWEs%2BfQ5lSlAEa7Un3wRodR%2BETJsra%2BAP81%2BvwyPPaCA9jkkKsRATD%5CnfvunBWyjwFAVSck/TzOaOeKgyGj7MQ4KnuzGRwIDAQABAoIBADCFrJ41/yYWcCjY%5CneTE0sg1aBzUGeQiMZaQABpA%2BL6TAAhTKs7QJEObYjd8r8x83JDDtlzAq67dEmS7N%5CnHrsUm/NhByTJa6qZy348sfY9JqS8geSIC%2B4sRmQQ9oLn15WF08tjyiuxgjR8u%2Bak%5CnZVHr4/M%2BWb4ofLODsOneplaaP0n2N7hcQneDfyrRYrAaqVt73jumSSt9N%2BjT%2Bw1M%5CnGKf/NRUXqJv4XaEtVOOX49fKUbFVQaSwGLqn/ySusKCI9XjjhrRTAoW%2B3rlLq6AJ%5CnWLVyEiBSXrZEo7fW2iRRsGb9/IMEGZCihPmxRMdWkxTwHEBaR2huPYGY6M4LQ8AQ%5Cn67Oub/kCgYEAvyyzHYE6rA0mzRjPdEm8vGqNiGGjoR%2Bkks6zGq7w8jK%2BijvYGRkn%5Cn1sKSAVpnXTXWlvXw8/NumQ9PFLoMbWPHESvoklOOtQasHyikH/AmmihdakwEALws%5CnytBbUwCKwp3UTBDfqi7Bp%2BUfkqWjN2vPsq7Wogf/6Bo50EYQPy6Rq0sCgYEA75Ei%5CnqOficXtYjQ4iZ/vhU7uNcQbq6ncrH5NCeAUViwKJ4Ay5jbOC/kxB9k8ryjuD/xOR%5CngC/COdjxUNAxkqPBqJv2/jMIYFbVT27H/DyZBbocSG/sT7/wQqEMBerz7AxQ0GH6%5Cn1XnJtbk7w39bzt4gJprlNzixIPBgQOQY8j6JV3UCgYEAmYnx9SFkGOibIB/sBc5u%5Cn%2BbhuIXmhrHc4evvtluGn/C1LIMR9g3LTr0UndFTCLXde%2BHFgat05F07XSaM%2B9eAr%5Cn8huct2DKfZN1S7UdU9VRe4AtvoB8uoZnRyBeKGSIDVQrPEhVCl5xBEIdwG6tjoZV%5CnEoIfOZVJL4VYp3CN/eCN988CgYBb0yWV2EvTc5PdfS1y7fjQP3NXf29Lr6G32JoB%5CnpvE69x4h4r68sbHkBxbBclc2jNlrS/TZTXUE90KH10UpD9uK5T0m8iijxKS%2BbZf5%5Cn9sAwkcWFfmD1sHxHDbOuEQCt2YqgVO3wJV5LaVSe%2BpIWGM35/iUdpX0/QuOh%2B8wU%5CnDiRWgQKBgDvHkVes2seQ/5P/bEktOx9ony2epy6v7xTFnjfN9xsB0pInWK4IPF6H%5CnmCO%2BCSzmrA8KdLUhwvjkT85eaFPfL0T8MJ6voL/vNHpsxGMrHyfP9FrfCNRZi4Un%5CniztySsfnjt8GY9uFNuJ03tUFlUNuSGkUfS8byUMsBWr%2BLxZY4xOf%5Cn-----END%20RSA%20PRIVATE%20KEY-----%27,%27%27,%27RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5%27,%27SHA-1%27)&input=SzhjUzJSMGFWQ0pLVW5qSVQxY3h6aXd5T0h0cEhWL1luRVZQWWZidmh4VUxEMkc5MUo2MEdSajZPSkNqL2VzVnVkdDJqQnY1bWpIUTVqTEJaY2xpSm9xLy9ic1Q4UEVtaEVTeUk0OEwycS85NzZlYXY3YUh2Vy90WFFzbFlBT01VQzY2WktZWFJ2WWRqOWNBWVR4S2hxdXIzVzZ6c2w0ZlorNUZFcXAyNGRGKzA0bDZCaHZjUEwwdFJLMUxKazJDZ0lZVVdNY3lrZ0hKMmMwRUFmL2dzakNYVnBWdzM0aDQ4ZVJKMHVMZGpFZVpPL3JtQmRBVDlsRHh3Y1ZlQTlyVWJhTER1VElQWGhPbTVlVmlPUTl3dXJuVFF5dWtRSTh6cXVFbWFSdXA5N0VTcmhlZDV3MkVaY1JhbEg2SFN5U1MrV1NXcmlrbDRicnlRa3RMcEJGMWx3PT0)), proving the correct encryption by the Powershell script.